# htaccess rewrite rule with hyphen in tld

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tld

I am trying to write htaccess file that would convert

```
http://subdomain.my-tld.com/
```

to

```
http://my-tld.com/file.php?var=subdomain
```

Notice the hyphen in the tld.

Here's the htaccess I am using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On 

# Rewrite sub domains. 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.my-tld\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.my-tld\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /file.php?var=%2 [QSA,L]
```

I am using the very same code for another domain in the very same server and it is working great, but it is not for this domain. I am guessing that the problem is with the hyphen in this domain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried escaping the hyphen, as in `my\-tld`?

Comment: @neokio yes, but no luck

Comment: The `-` shouldn't matter, they've only got special meaning inside of the `[` and `]` brackets.

Comment: @JonLin then how would you write a code that would achieve this purpose?

Comment: Those rules work fine in my blank htaccess file if I access "blahblah.my-tld.com"

Comment: use rewritelog(2.2) or loglevel rewrite:trace8 to at least narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

For me, these rules make the server return "Internal Server Error", and the error log will print

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error

I'm not sure why it works for another domain as you said, but just try adding this condition before the final RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !var=
```

Make it pass the url alreay get param "var".